# parsing the content of a line using java in eclipse

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

Can anyone give me a example for parsing the content of the file and display the particular words from that file after the delimiters using the StringTokenizer class in java.

thank you all,

actually i tried this code
 public class word 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String line=" ";
    int lineNo;

    try
    {
        FileReader fr= new FileReader("f:/parse1.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        for(lineNo = 1; lineNo <=10; lineNo++)
        {
            if(lineNo == 2)
            {
            line = br.readLine();

            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(line,"-->");

            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String s=st.nextToken();
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            }else
            {
                br.readLine();
            }


        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

My content in the text file is:

(FusionResultProcessor.java:145) - -------------------> Feed id: 0001 processing

SUCCEEDED.    ProcessingTimeTook: 5 milliseconds.

got the output as,

(FusionResultProcessor.java:145) 
 Feed id: 0001 processing

I want to print only the feed id: xxx and i dont want to print the (fusion...). that is

> I want to print the data after the delimiter">".

Comment: Short answer, no - long answer, try it yourself, if it doesn't work, post what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. At least google it.

Comment: You can consider `Scanner` class also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example (not tested), that use a pipe delimiter :

```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      //Create a StringTokenizer and pass the line to it
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strLine);
      while(st.hasMoreTokens())
          String token = st.nextToken("|");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file.txt")));
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line).append("\n");
} 
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(stringBuffer.toString());
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String word = st.nextToken();
    System.out.println(word);
}
```